# dividing DataFrame rows together to create new column value

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a grouped up DataFrame but i want to find out a new value by divind the columns values together, example:

```
NAME    QUANTITY    VALUE    PRICE
JOHN       4        100      12.5
```

This is what i have but i need to divide quantity, value and price to make a NEW column with that value

so i will have a new dataframe with this:

```
NAME    QUANTITY    VALUE    PRICE    TOTAL
JOHN       4        100      12.5      0.0032
```

I have tried to group up and perform a sum but the syntax is not correct.

Any advice?

Comment: Please define `dividing DataFrame rows together`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['TOTAL'] = df.QUANTITY / df.VALUE / df.PRICE

>>> df
   NAME  QUANTITY  VALUE  PRICE   TOTAL
0  JOHN         4    100   12.5  0.0032
```

Comment: absolutely perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df['TOTAL'] = df['QUANTITY'].div(df['VALUE']).div(df['PRICE'])
print (df)
   NAME  QUANTITY  VALUE  PRICE   TOTAL
0  JOHN         4    100   12.5  0.0032
```